Book that ends with someone knocking on the door
The only detail I remember of the book/story was that it ended with someone/something banging/scratching on the front door, but the characters never find out what it is. In the context I heard of it, it was used to compare horror to terror.

Not "The Monkey's Paw"?

I thought of "House Taken Over" by Julio Cortázar, but it's not exactly the same ending.

The short story Knock by Fredric Brown starts with:

There is a sweet little horror story that is only two sentences long:
“The last man on Earth sat alone in a room.  There was a knock on the door…”

It also ends with the same two sentences.
